# How is the square of $\operatorname{sgn}(x)$ defined?

Tags: real-analysis, definition

I want to know that if we define the sign function for $x\in\mathbb{R}$
$$
\operatorname{sgn}(x):=\begin{cases}
-1&\text{if $x<0$}\\
0&\text{if $x=0$} \\
1&\text{if $x>0$}
\end{cases}
$$
Can we safely state that $\operatorname{sgn}^2(x)=1$? In other words how can we appropriately perform power operations on this operator?

Comment: It looks to me that $\operatorname{sgn}^2(0)=0$

Comment: $\text{sgn}^2(x) = {\text{sgn}}(x)^2$ or $\text{sgn}^2(x) = \text{sgn}(\text{sgn}(x))$? In neither case is it true that $\text{sgn}^2(x) = 1$ for all $x$, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What we can safely say is that $$\mathrm{sgn}(x)^2=\begin{cases}1&x\neq0\\0&x=0\end{cases}.$$ In general, $$f[\mathrm{sgn}(x)]=\begin{cases}f(-1)&x\lt0\\f(0)&x=0\\f(1)&x\gt0\end{cases}.$$